# Why my menu is merging with the input field ? I want it to be responsive

Tags: html, css

I am new to HTML CSS, can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

:root {
  --pink: #ff6161;
  --white: #fff;
  --black: #292828;
  --font: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

header {
  min-height: 100px;
  max-width: 100%;
  background-color: var(--pink);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.menu {
  max-width: 10rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.menu-items {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-right: 30px;
  font-family: var(--font);
  font-size: 20px;
}

.menu-items a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: var(--black);
}

.search-bar {
  width: 700px;
}

.inp {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="search-bar">
    <input class="inp" type="text" />
  </div>
  <ul class="menu">
    <i class="fa-solid fa-house"></i>
    <li class="menu-items"><a href="#"> Home</a></li>
    <i class="fa-solid fa-store"></i>
    <li class="menu-items"><a href="#">Store</a></li>
    <i class="fa-solid fa-headset"></i>
    <li class="menu-items"><a href="#">Support</a></li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

Comment: you mean that the value of the input is the html code? try closing the input tag, like `<input class="inp" type="text" />`

Comment: Can you post a picture of your output?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/uom3ayrd/1/
TRY RESIZING THE WINDOW

Comment: What do you want it to look like on narrower devices? You've set the search bar to a fixed 700px as far as I can see. There isn't room for everything on one line in narrower viewports.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're using `align items: center` and `justify-content: center` in your header at the same time.

You're basically forcing items inside header to move to the center.

Comment: I tried making justify content-space around and even removing justify content it still has same issue.

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS, when you are modifying the header, you are putting all elements inside of it in the same position.
Something you could to fix this is, give the header a relative position, and then manipulate each element inside the header individually.

Comment: make sure to include a runnable code snippet to explain and illustrate your proposed solution better, makes for a much cleaner and thorough answer

Answer (score 0):

The sum of the text widths of the menu `Home Store Support` will be greater than `max-width: 10rem;`

```
.menu { 
    display: flex; 
    justify-content: center; 
    align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `display` for `menu` to `contents`:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

:root {
  --pink: #ff6161;
  --white: #fff;
  --black: #292828;
  --font: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

header {
  min-height: 100px;
  max-width: 100%;
  background-color: var(--pink);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.menu {
  max-width: 10rem;
  display: contents;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.menu-items {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-right: 30px;
  font-family: var(--font);
  font-size: 20px;
}

.menu-items a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: var(--black);
}

.search-bar {
  width: 700px;
}

.inp {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="search-bar">
    <input class="inp" type="text" />
  </div>
  <ul class="menu">
    <i class="fa-solid fa-house"></i>
    <li class="menu-items"><a href="#"> Home</a></li>
    <i class="fa-solid fa-store"></i>
    <li class="menu-items"><a href="#">Store</a></li>
    <i class="fa-solid fa-headset"></i>
    <li class="menu-items"><a href="#">Support</a></li>
  </ul>
</header>
```